# How to add all event listeners at once in js?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm creating some kind of UI, and I had an idea to create a spotlight in JS. That would mean that if user completely wouldn't interact with the website for example 2 minutes execute a function. That brings me to the question: how to trigger a function after any event

I would like something like that:

```
document.addEventListener("all", spotlight)
```

I know that I can do it, but it would be annoying and I know that there must be some more elegant solution

JS:

```
document.addEventListener(----, spotlight) 
 



function spotlight() {
     spotlightCanvas.classList.remove("hide")
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: the `all` event doesn't exit.

Comment: @8HoLoN Of course, I know that, but I just used it as an example

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like: [List of events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

```js
const event = ['click','focus'];

let watchdog = new Date();
event.forEach(ev=>{
    document.addEventListener(ev,_=>{
        watchdog = new Date();
    });
    
});
setInterval(_=>{
    if(new Date() - watchdog > 120000){
        spotlight();
    }
},100);
```

Comment: That is the opposite of what the OP is after.

Comment: that the only approach the OP can do because there no string representing all events, so no it's no the opposite at all.

Comment: You misunderstand. Your code runs `spotlight` when any of the events (that get listeners because of your `forEach()`) fire. The OP wants to fire `spotLight` when none of the events fire for 120 seconds. This requires a timer that gets reset when any of the events are triggered.

Comment: hm ok, that's not what I understand from my reading of his problem, ok.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no one event that represents all events** but you certainly can do what you are seeking. Since there are many ways to interact with a website (mouse clicks, keyboard clicks, mouse movements, etc.) you'll need to set up a timer and when any of these events happen, reset it. If the timer reaches 120 seconds, then some other function can happen.

See the comments in the working example below that only waits 5 seconds.

```js
// Make an array of all the event names you want to listen for
const event = ['click','mousemove', 'touchstart', 'keydown'];

let maxSeconds = 5;  // Amount of time document has to be inactive
let inactive = 0;    // Amount of time document has currently been inactive

// This is a function that will run approximately every second
let timer = setInterval(function(){ 
  // If we add one to the inactive time and have reached the max...
  if(++inactive === maxSeconds){
    spotlight(); // Run the desired function
  } 
}, 1000); // Run again in about a second


// Loop over each of the strings in the array
event.forEach(ev=>{
    // Add an event listener for each event name
    document.addEventListener(ev, function(){
        inactive = 0; // reset the amount of inactive time
    });
});

function spotlight(){
  alert("Time's up!");
}
```

Comment: Of course, I know that I need to use a timer I have the timer logic done, but I thought it was unnececesary

Comment: @PythonisFine As you are new to Stack Overflow, you should understand that we don't know you and what you know and don't know. We only know what you post, so to respond to myself and others with "of course I know that" isn't as obvious as you may think it is since you didn't post anything that would make us think that you knew it. We're here to help. My answer clearly addresses your question and posts a working solution. Please up vote all helpful answers and consider marking mine as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to just listen for `mousemove` events. The user will almost always move the mouse with any interaction.

Reset a 2 minute timer every time the mouse moves. When there is no movement for 2 minutes, the `spotlight` function runs.

```
let timer
window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(spotlight, 120000)
})
function spotlight(){
    console.lgo("the mouse disn't move for 2 minutes")
}
```

You might include an option for `keydown` events for users who don't use the mouse, but I don't think you need to listen to ALL events.

Comment: I thought so, but 1. mobile users don't have mousemove or keydown 2. There are still some like scroll or some more touch events. Ok, that would still give us, like, 6 events ok, I could totally do some array with them. But I just thought if there's not any allEventsArr.forEach method... But thanks

Comment: That's true, you'll need `touch` and `scroll`. But don't forget that `all` events also include `load`, `animationend`, etc. etc. etc. I think there are hundreds of events. Maybe not a good idea to listen to all of them :)